# I want to buy something that lets me mount my bike on the wall. What could I buy?

Tags: product-rec

I want to buy something that lets me mount my bike on the wall. What's a product I could use? Something sturdy, cheap, and easy to set up.

Comment: This is a question without the ability to have one right answer.  It is also a question better answered with a Google search.

Answer (score 2):

A [floor-to-ceiling bike hanger](http://www.etrailer.com/Accessories-and-Parts/Swagman/S80960.html?feed=npn&gclid=CKPowIWN8LECFfNxMgodByIA6w) is one option.

Or a fancier [storage rack](http://www.autoanything.com/bike-racks/69A5367A0A0.aspx?kc=ffproduct&gclid=CN7J6JWO8LECFdNxMgod6ywAVw).

Or a simple [wall hook](http://www.nycewheels.com/ac-rack-storage-racor-b1.html?gclid=CJyXtqmN8LECFQgUKgod7yMAvg).